# How can I create an Azure Role-Based Access Control rule to authorize a user the ability to invoke an azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-web-roles, azure-app-service-plans

I would like to give a specific user the ability to invoke (but not modify or delete) an Azure function through the Azure web portal.

I am following the [documentation for creating custom roles in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles), but it is unclear which action I should assign the user to.  I am referencing the corresponding [Azure Resource Manager Resource Provider Options documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-resource-provider-operations), but can't seem to find an action that would apply the permissions that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions cannot be invoked via ARM, which means that RBAC doesn't factor into it. The portal actually uses ARM to fetch the admin key for the Function App and uses that to invoke the manual test APIs.

What you're trying to do won't work because of the lack of more granular RBAC permissions (plus its a data plane API)

If you just want to give certain folks access to certain Functions, there are other options like adding AAD in front of your Function App and then giving them the URL to the Function. If you expand on what your scenario is, I can try to give more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Chris Anderson-MSFT. Our scenario is that we would like to leverage the azure portal as a sort of "help desk" tool for our help desk team to run certain azure functions on an ad-hoc basis.  The idea would be to give our help-desk team the ability to run (and only run, not delete or modify) an azure function when needed to address support issues.

Comment: It'd probably be worth just building a tiny web portal behind AAD and not giving them access to the Functions itself. There's not really a safe way to grant "run only" permissions via ARM RBAC.